# how can I run adplus in crash mode but not have it write a dump on shutdown?

Tags: adplus

If I run:

adplus.exe -pmn "MyClient.exe" -o "d:\DumpFiles" -crash

When I shut down I get a dump file created:

FULLDUMP_FirstChance_epr_Process_Shut_Down_MyClient.EXE__333c_2012-05-29_14-29-04-654_2690

Is there a way to run adplus in crash mode but not get this Process_Shut_Down dump created?
(or does this mean there is an exception during shutdown?)

I want to monitor my application for run-time exceptions but don't want to fill up the hard drive if the program is exiting normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a configuration file when running adplus:

This is the contents of my file:  D:\DumpFiles\conf.txt

```
<ADPlus Version='2'>
  <Exceptions>  
        <Exception Code="epr">
            <Actions1>Void</Actions1>
            <Actions2>Void</Actions2>
        </Exception> 
   </Exceptions>
</ADPlus>
```

Now we can run: adplus.exe -c D:\DumpFiles\conf.txt -pmn notepad++  -crash -o "D:\DumpFiles"

Using the configuration file fixes this problem and adplus seems to be smart enough to just apply this “epr” exception rule as the only difference.  I used WinMerge to compare the generated “DebuggerScript.txt” files.

NOTE: if you taskkill notepad++ you won't get a dump if you are running with this configuration file.